# Page with 2 Listboxes OnSelectedIndexChanged is firing the same listbox

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have web page which is ContentPage of MasterPages and it has 2 ListBoxes with many items inside.
The code for the 1st Listbox is

```
<div id="electrics" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel7" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox5" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Font-Size="12pt" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox5_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
                <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress3" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel7">
                    <ProgressTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1112" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/ajax.gif" />
                    </ProgressTemplate>
                </asp:UpdateProgress>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ListBox5" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code for the second is the same only change the ID.

When i click the listbox the code open a webpage with parameters from the selected listbox.

The page shows OK and the parameters are showing correct.

When I press back and select the second Listbox, it fires again the first listbox so the new webpage shows the same parameters from the first listbox.

This is the problem, the second listbox is not firing, its only fires the first clicked. 
I have to reload the page to be able to click the second listbox.

Comment: When you say, the code is same just changed the `ID` that means you have not changed the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event in it. Which will ultimately trigger the same event.

Comment: The code is the same i mean that its doing the same thing.
The second listbox fires only after refresh the page and then of coarse its not firing the first.